# What is relation between Project and VPC in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In google cloud I want to understand relation between project and VPC. Can vpc span multiple projects? or Can we say vpc is always in one project?

Answer (score 0):

Per definition a VPC pertains only to a certain project, but you can share a VPC creating a [shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc). Shared VPC allows an organization to connect resources from multiple projects to a common VPC network, so that they can communicate with each other securely and efficiently using internal IPs from that network. If you go [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc#use_cases) you can find some examples of shared VPCs.

Answer (score 0):

Projects can contain multiple VPC networks. Unless you create an organizational policy that prohibits it, new projects start with a default network (an auto mode VPC network) that has one subnetwork (subnet) in each region.

You can also see more information about shared VPC: Shared VPC allows an organization to connect resources from multiple projects to a common Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) network, so that they can communicate with each other securely and efficiently using internal IPs from that network.
More information: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc#use_cases

We also have VPC Peering: VPC networks can be connected to other VPC networks in different projects or organizations by using VPC Network Peering.
More information: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering